# Windows drive unallocated after moving drive to external on USB 3.0

Tags: windows, hard-drive, usb

I have swapped the HDD in my laptop with an SSD and reinstalled Windows.

I was hoping to put the old HDD into a USB 3.0 enclosure and transfering some files over, but the drive shows up as unallocated now.

How can I fix this?

[image: Disk Manager]

Comment: Was the old drive encrypted (bitlocker/truecrypt/etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

Forgot that there was an HDD password set. The drive kept freezing because it was never prompted for the password.

Fixed the issue by temporarily placing it on SATA and clearing its password in BIOS.